# Handling names and values of attributes

Tags: python, attributes

I am probably approaching this wrong, but would appreciate being straightened out.

I would like to be able to use both the values and the names of some attributes of a class

Sample:

```
class DoStuff(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a="Alpha"
        self.b="Beta"
        self.c="Gamma"
    def printStuff(self):
        for thing in [self.a, self.b, self.c]:
            print NAMEOFTHING, thing
```

What I want is:

> ```
> a Alpha
> b Beta
> c Gamma
> ```

How can I get that?

Edit:  Some confusion because my example showed me printing ALL the values.  Instead I want this:

> ```
> a Alpha
> c Gamma
> ```

with the list for my print method just having 'a' and 'c' in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest you could get is:

```
for thing in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    print thing, getattr(self, thing)
```

Variables can have multiple names and aren't aware of their own name, so if you know it's 'a', then you can use `getattr` to resolve the lookup.

Another option (although not greatly different than above)

```
to_get = ['a', 'b', 'c']
from operator import attrgetter
blah = zip(to_get, attrgetter(*to_get)(self))
```

Comment: Ah! That's what I was looking for.  Just not thinking about it right.  Put the NAMES of the attributes in the list, not the contents.

Answer (score 8):

The way your class and `for` loop are set up, there is nothing you can put in place of `NAMEOFTHING` to get to the names of those variables.  Here are a few alternatives on how you can modify your approach:

- Use a dictionary instead of individual attributes, and then provide a list of keys in your `for` loop:

  ```
  class DoStuff(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.names = {"a": "Alpha",
                        "b": "Beta",
                        "c": "Gamma"}
      def printStuff(self):
          for name in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
              print name, self.names[name]
  ```
- Use the attribute names in your list and then use `getattr()`:

  ```
  class DoStuff(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.a="Alpha"
          self.b="Beta"
          self.c="Gamma"
      def printStuff(self):
          for name in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
              print name, getattr(self, name)
  ```

Comment: These are probably better (especially the dictionary option), but you could also pull it off using introspection with dir().  Take a look at: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-pyint/index.html

Comment: The `dict` approach is a good suggestion - potentially even an `OrderedDict` depending on the exact requirement

Answer (score 1):

Following on Jon's answer, you might also find it helpful to set the list of attributes you want to include in the output as an optional argument:

```
def printStuff(self, included=['a', 'c']):
    for thing in included:
        print thing, getattr(self, thing)
```

which makes it easy to generate *both* outputs, by saying `DoStuff().printStuff()` to get just the values of `a` and `c`, or `DoStuff().printStuff(['a', 'b', 'c'])` to get all three. Of course, this *allows* for varying output—if it's an explicit design-goal that the set of fields being printed is invariant, this would be counterproductive.

Answer (score 0):

```
# You can use __dict__
>>> class x:
>>>     def __init__(self):
>>>         self.a = 1
>>>         self.b = 2
>>>         self.c = 3
>>>         self.d = 4

>>>     def prnt(self):
>>>         limit = "b", "c"
>>>         return {k:v for (k, v) in self.__dict__.iteritems()if k in limit}

>>> r = x()
>>> print r.prnt()
    {'b': 2, 'c': 3}

# __dict__ can be also done outside the class

limit = "b", "c"
print {k:v for (k, v) in r.__dict__.iteritems()if k in limit}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only works when I want every attribute.  I wasn't entirely clear in my question.

Comment: You can use it when you want only certain attributes

Comment: @Skip check now, it has limit

Comment: Thank you, but I think Jon's answer best fits my needs.